# What is the difference between context free grammar and an Other grammar?

Tags: programming-languages, context-free-grammar

What grammars are not context free?
Please give me examples that are not context free.

Is this grammar context free?

```
A->aSb|aaS|aaaS|B
S->aSb|Bb|lambda
B->Bb|lambda
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com or cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar: You may have just stated the most ridiculous sentence of all time on StackOverflow.

Comment: Not really. CS and programming are related, like architecture and building construction.

Comment: @Mehrdad When a more specific stackexchange site is available, questions related to that area should be posted there instead, even if it's related to programming like with [tex.se] or [dba.se].

Comment: @deviantfan thank U , I know the definition But its hard to understand , i want some examples of grammar are not context free .

Comment: @Barmar context-free grammar is tagged  , this tag isnt for CS?

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, a ridiculous sentence doesn't have to be wrong. It can be very technically correct and still be ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammar is context-free, because there's no *context* around the left-hand side. See below.

Assuming:

- The Greek letters like α, β, and γ are arbitrary productions
- Uppercase letters like X and Y are nonterminal symbols
- Lowercase letters like z are terminal symbols
- ε is the special empty production

We have the following definitions:

1. **Regular** grammars are those whose rules can be written in the forms:

   ```
   X: z Y
   X: z
   X: ε
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   Digits: '0' Digits
   Digits: '1' Digits
   Digits: '2' Digits
   ...
   Digits: '9' Digits
   Digits: ε
   ```
2. **Context-free** grammars are those whose rules can be written in the form:

   ```
   X: α
   ```

   In other words, **only single nonterminals** can be transformed at a time, independently of what might surround them.

   For example:

   ```
   Expression: AdditiveExpression
   AdditiveExpression: AdditiveExpression '+' MultiplicativeExpression
   AdditiveExpression: AdditiveExpression '-' MultiplicativeExpression
   AdditiveExpression: MultiplicativeExpression
   MultiplicativeExpression: MultiplicativeExpression '*' PrimaryExpression
   MultiplicativeExpression: MultiplicativeExpression '/' PrimaryExpression
   MultiplicativeExpression: PrimaryExpression
   PrimaryExpression: Number
   PrimaryExpression: '(' Expression ')'
   ```
3. **Context-sensitive** grammars are those whose rules can be written in the form:

   ```
   αXγ: αβγ
   ```

   In other words, the *context* around `X` can help you decide that `X` should be transformed into `β`, but the context *itself* does not become transformed.

   For example:

   ```
   Expression: 'x' Foo 'y'
   'x' Foo 'y': 'x' Bar 'y'
   Bar: 'z'
   ```

   **A more realistic example** that shows why this is useful [can be found on Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163830/4890).
4. **Unrestricted** grammars are those whose rules can be written in the form:

   ```
   αXγ: β
   ```

   In other words, *any* sequence of symbols containing a nonterminal can be manipulated into *any* other sequence of symbols. Basically, this represents *arbitrary* manipulation of memory, or Turing-completeness.

   For example:

   ```
   Expression: 'x' Foo 'y'
   'x' Foo 'y': 'z'
   ```

   You never see these in practice.

Comment: show me one grammar isn't context free please.

Comment: @Nastaran: I've done that, maybe you didn't refresh after I wrote it? It's under *"For example"* in #3.

Comment: "You never see these in practice."  One does, in fact, see them occasionally, but usually they're just called rewrite rules or something similar, and not referred to as grammars.

Comment: Also note that β must be nonempty in the definition of a context-sensitive grammar (otherwise you've got the equivalent of an unrestricted grammar instead!)